# Python + Cron: No such file or directory

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script that updates a .txt file.

When I run the file manually in the terminal it works, it also updates the file. However, this seems to only be a problem when it is run with cron.

The response in the log file is:

> No such file or directory: 'uploads/test.txt'

The cron command for this is:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/script.py >> /root/log.log  2>&1
```

I'm literally stumped. Any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path to the `test.txt` file in `script.py`?

Comment: I tried using `~/root/uploads.test.txt` is that the absolute path?

Comment: That doesn't look right. Try `/root/uploads/test.txt`! Without the `~` which is the path to the curretn user's home folder.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy clearly I meant `/` not `.` and the uploads/test.txt is references in the script that is run.

Comment: By default, cron jobs run in `/`, so `uploads/test.txt` will be looking for `/uploads/test.txt`, which you probably don't have.

Comment: That file exists in the same spot as the script.py

Comment: Yes, but `.` isn't the location of the script, it's the current working directory of the process that started the script. Entirely different things.

Comment: ...that said, making it clear that that's the source of the misunderstanding here has allowed a dupe to be identified.

Comment: @JamesG, ...btw, `~` is syntax for a shell expansion. It doesn't have meaning to the OS-level `open()` syscall or other language wrappers for it;  there's an `os.path` library call you need to use if you want `~` to be replaced with the current user's home directory in Python.

Answer (score 1):

`uploads/test.txt` is a relative path.  Cron is not running from the parent directory of `uploads`.  Use an absolute path to uploads (eg. `/data/foo/uploads/test.txt`, or `cwd` to parent directory of `uploads`.

Comment: You might also suggest `cd /data/foo && exec python ...` as an alternative (the `exec` is just a performance optimization -- means that the shell doesn't need to stick around in memory after `python` is started -- but the `&&` is critical: Means we don't try to run the Python interpreter if we can't `cd` to the directory that the script expects to be started from).